# ##N delay cycles inside class

Tags: system-verilog

##N inside an interface with a default clocking block is supposed to delay by N cycles

If I have a class inside an interface, it appears that this is not working.  The LRM doesnt seems to specify anything wrong and I am not getting any compile errors

See following snippet, where there is an accessor class inside an interface and the class has a member for waiting cycles.  Calling this task seems not introducing any delay

```
interface my_if (
  input logic clk,
  inout logic valid,
  inout logic[1:0] req );
  
  default clocking cb @(posedge clk);
    inout valid;
    inout req;
  endclocking

  class accessor_c;
    function new();
    endfunction
    
    task wait_cycles(int value);
      ##value;
    endtask
      
  endclass
  
  initial begin
    accessor_c acc;
    acc = new();
    #100;
    $display("%t: call wait", $time);
    acc.wait_cycles(1);
    $display("%t: after wait", $time);
  end
  
endinterface
```

Both of above display prints same time.

Code on edaplayground where a wait directly in interface works while inside class is not working
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/9_u_

Answer (score 2):

You have a race condition—it has nothing to do with the `##value` being inside a class.

The race is caused by the fact that you have a `#100` delay in your `initial` block, and that is in race with the `always` block in your testbench that produces a *posedge clk* at time 100. So the call to `wait_cycles` is in a race whether it gets called before or after the clock edge.

To fix this, change `#100` to a value that does not coincide the posedge clock, or better use a delay like `repeat (5) @cb`.

In general it's better to use the `repeat(N) @cb` syntax than the `##N` syntax because you can use it where no default clocking block is allowed (like in a package) and you can access different clocking blocks hierarchically through a virtual interface.